# Java - Trying to output to a file where if the user's login is there only replace the balance

Tags: java, file, output

My program is basically a user's name, and balance, this is stored in a file, when the user updates their profile, I want their balance to update too, but not their name, as they already have it in the file.
The name and balance are split with a comma. In the file it is displayed like this:

```
Stacey,0.02
```

(The name is actually a randomly generated number+letter string, but I thought I'd keep it simple here.)

When I try to write to the file with this code, it doesn't write anything.
Code:

```
        btnSaveUserid.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = txtUserid.getText().toString();
            String balance = beedcoin1Balance.getText().toString();
            File file = new File("d:/users/joel/desktop/code/usersid.txt");
            BufferedReader br = null;
            try {

                String sCurrentLine;

                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d:/users/joel/desktop/code/usersid.txt"));
                List<String> terms = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> ttlBalance = new ArrayList<String>();

                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] ar = sCurrentLine.split(",");
                    String userid = ar[0];
                    terms.add(userid);
                    System.out.println(terms);
                }
                if(terms.contains(text)) {
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("d:/users/joel/desktop/code/usersid.txt")));
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);


                    while(scanner.hasNextLine());
                        String line = scanner.nextLine();

                        String[] ar = line.split(",");
                        String userid = ar[0];
                        String bdcv1val = ar[1];
                        int lineNum = 0;
                        lineNum++;
                        if(line.equals(userid)) {
                            Path path = Paths.get("d:/users/joel/desktop/code/usersid.txt");
                            Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

                            String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);
                            content = content.replace(txtUserid.toString(), txtUserid.toString());
                            Files.write(path, content.getBytes(charset));

                            out.println(text + "," + balance);
                            System.out.println("Successfully printed to usersid.txt");
                        }
                }
                else {
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("d:/users/joel/desktop/code/usersid.txt")));

                    out.println(text + "," + balance);
                    System.out.println("Successfully printed to usersid.txt");

                }
            } catch (IOException el) {
                el.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if(br != null)br.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

It all takes place in a button's action listener, and this code outputs the "Successfully printed to file" but doesn't actually print it to the file. I'm honestly perplexed, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you have exceptions in console. First of all you are trying to write to the file you've opened for reading in the same time. Try to refactor your code with dedicated steps of data flow - read (close file), process, write

Comment: Thanks, I added a close in, it works now but doesn't add the user's name to a new line.